# Java get Array from HashMap

Tags: java

I'm currently calling a service using XML-RPC and get a `HashMap<Object, Object>` response.
I would like to get the array within the response.

What the response looks like:

```
"serviceClassCurrent":1000,
"serviceRemovalDate":"Jun 6, 2017 12:00:00 PM",
   "dedicatedAccountInformation":[  
      {  
         "expiryDate":"Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM",
         "dedicatedAccountID":1,
         "dedicatedAccountValue1":"0"
      },
      {  
         "expiryDate":"Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM",
         "dedicatedAccountID":2,
         "dedicatedAccountValue1":"0"
      },
```

How would I get the `dedicatedAccountInformation`? I thought about using Gson to parse it and get it that way, but that means additional dependencies. The value for key `dedicatedAccountInformation` is a object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a JSON String?

Comment: No, its a HashMap<Object, Object>, where key "dedicatedAccountInformation" value is a object. I just printed it that way to show what it looks like.

Comment: Then why would you think of using `GSon` if its not a JSON string?

Comment: Array of which object you want?

Comment: If it is a Map, why don't you just call map.get("dedicatedAccountInformation")? You can cast it into the needed type

Comment: @Jaskey, thanks for the comment, its exactly what I was looking for, but to what do I cast it? the spec I have for this legacy system states that dedicatedAccountInformation is a <struct> of arrays which is confusing.

Comment: Try it out in a debugger  and have a look at it?